# How to avoid flicker when reloading expandable table view cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview, expand, flicker

I need the cells of a `UITableView` to be expanded, but I see a flicker when doing this.

I have this implementation:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Switch row state
    expandedFlags[indexPath.row] = !expandedFlags[indexPath.row]

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Is there any way to avoid the flicking when reloading the cells? I've read several posts but didn't work for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
....
tableView.endUpdates()
```

already has its own animation UIView animation what probably makes the flicker

Answer (score 0):

Hi After spending so many hours on this, I finally found the solution to stop this flicker issue in table view while you are expanding or collapsing your tableview cell.

In First step, you have to get your current offset of tableview and then stop the uiview animation and tell your tableview that you are going to update some rows in the tableview. Then pass your current index [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 3)] like this is mine. Your tableview works like charm.

```
let currentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 3)], with: .none)
tableView.endUpdates()
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
self.tableView.setContentOffset(currentOffset, animated: false)
```